# Subclass Enum to add validation

Tags: python, enums

The Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicatefreeenum) for the `enum` module contains the following example of subclassing `Enum`. The resulting class can be used to create enums that also validate that they have no two members with the same value.

```python3
>>> class DuplicateFreeEnum(Enum):
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...         cls = self.__class__
...         if any(self.value == e.value for e in cls):
...             a = self.name
...             e = cls(self.value).name
...             raise ValueError(
...                 "aliases not allowed in DuplicateFreeEnum:  %r --> %r"
...                 % (a, e))
```

However, as a method of adding validation, this method is inelegant and restrictive. `__init__` is called once for each member, whereas in order to validate an enum as a whole, it makes more sense to look at every member of the enum together.

For instance, how would I validate that an enum has precisely two members, as below?

```
class PreciselyTwoEnum(Enum):
    ...  # ???

class Allowed(PreciselyTwoEnum):
    FOO = 1
    BAR = 2

class Disallowed(PreciselyTwoEnum):  # Should raise an error
    BAZ = 3
```

Can this be accomplished with a clever implementation of `__init__`? Is there another method that could be used — perhaps one that is called on the enum after it has been fully created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init_subclass__` is what you are looking for<sup>1</sup>:

```
class PreciselyTwoEnum(Enum):
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if len(cls.__members__) != 2:
            raise TypeError("only two members allowed")
```

and in use:

```
>>> class Allowed(PreciselyTwoEnum):
...     FOO = 1 
...     BAR = 2 
... 

>>> class Disallowed(PreciselyTwoEnum):  # Should raise an error
...     BAZ = 3 
... 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: only two members allowed
```

---

[1] `__init_subclass__` for `Enum` only works correctly in Python 3.11 or later, or by using the external `aenum` library v3.0 or later.<sup>2</sup>.

[2] Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: It'd be useful to add how you'd implement this with the aenum library, for those of us still on 3.10

Comment: @user: The above code works on both `enum.Enum` and `aenum.Enum` (v3.0+).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to subclass the `Enum` to achieve the required functionality, but it can be easily done with a class decorator:

```
from enum import Enum

def PreciselyTwoEnum(cls):
    members = len(cls.__members__)
    if members != 2:
        raise ValueError(f"two members expected in {cls.__name__!r}, but got {members}")
    return cls 

@PreciselyTwoEnum
class Allowed(Enum):
    FOO = 1 
    BAR = 2 

@PreciselyTwoEnum
class Disallowed(Enum):  # Should raise an error
    BAZ = 3
```

Comment: +1  upcoming in 3.11 are features which also do similar tasks using class decorator - see [`@enum.verify`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html#enum.verify)